# Error while executing Set-DrsRule using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set DrsRule for server using the below code

```
$hostname= $TOD_Data.name
try{

$OS = $TOD_Data.os
$dc = $TOD_Data.datacenter

Connect-VIServer -server 12.16.1.3

$VM = Get-VM | where {$_.Name -match $Hostname} | select -Unique

$cluster = Get-Cluster | where {$_.Name -eq "Standard"} | select Name
$cluster = $cluster.Name


$Win_Rule_2 = get-Cluster -name $cluster | Get-DrsVMHostRule -name "ST5_STRETCH_CLUSTER"


    
    if($OS -eq "Windows" -and $dc -eq "ST5")
    {
        Set-DrsRule -Rule $Win_Rule_2 -VM $VM -Enabled $true;
        Write-Host "$hostname added to $Win_Rule_2" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
    }
    
else
{write-host "Dual Site Hosting is false" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White}

}

catch
{
    write-host "$Error.Exception.Message" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White
}
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Rule'. Cannot convert the "ST5_STRETCH_CLUSTER" value of type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Cluster.DrsVMHostRuleImpl" to type "VMware.VimA
utomation.ViCore.Types.V1.Cluster.DrsRule"..Exception.Message
```

I checked the type of **$Win_Rule_2**, it is showing as

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Win_Rule_2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
False    False    DrsVMHostRuleImpl                        VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Util10.VersionedObjectImpl
```

Tried using below also, but getting error

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-DrsVMHostRule -Rule $Win_Rule_2 -VMGroup $Win_Rule_2_VMGroup -Server $VM -Enabled $true
```

**Error**

```
Set-DrsVMHostRule : Cannot bind parameter 'Server'. Cannot convert the "SW560PWMS1DB" value of type 
"VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.VM.UniversalVirtualMachineImpl" to type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.VIServer".
At line:1 char:74
+ ... le -Rule $Win_Rule_2 -VMGroup $Win_Rule_2_VMGroup -Server $VM -Enable ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-DrsVMHostRule], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.SetDrsVMHostRule
```

Please let me know what should I do the fix this issue

Comment: What if you use `Get-DRSRule` rather than `Get-DrsVMHostRule` or use `Set-DrsVMHostRule` rather than `Set-DrsRule`? I think it would be best to not combine old commands with new commands.

Comment: @AdminOfThings: Please check the update

Comment: `-Server` in `Set-DrsVMHostRule` is the vCenter server not the VM.

Comment: It looks like you really want to use `Set-DrsRule` so that you can target a specific VM. So I would switch to using `Get-DrsRule` in the earlier query so that the output and input types align.

Comment: @AdminOfThings: When I am using `Get-DrsRule`, I am not getting the list  VM host rules. so used this

Comment: I think you are going to need to create a cluster group using `New-DrsClusterGroup` or update an existing one using `Set-DrsClusterGroup` to include your VM(s). Then apply that cluster group to your rule using `Set-DrsVMHostRule`.